# Space in SQLite query

Tags: android, sqlite, sql-like

```
WHERE g.value like '" + lookingFor + "%'
```

I have an EditText which filters cursor from SQLite database. I want to take 'value' from 'g' table. For example one of 'value' is 'full stop'. When I input 'stop', query should find full stop.

If lookingFor is "efg", nothing is found. How to find "abcd efgh" when "efg" is typed?

PS. I do not want to get "abcd edfh" when I type "cd"

Comment: Can you explain further?

Comment: I think you might need a % at the start of the string as well, such as like '%" + lookingFor + "%'. Your code would be looking for a field that starts with efg and ends in anything

Comment: Unfortunately, it will find "abcd efgh" when I type "cd", right

Comment: It will. Didn't see your edit until after I posted. So why not include the space in the query eg LIKE '% " + lookingFor + "%'. This should find a field that has some characters at the start, followed by a space, followed by what you typed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before query:

```
String strSpace=" ";
```

Inside query:

```
 "...   WHERE g.value like '"+ lookingFor + "%' OR g.value like '%"+strSpace + lookingFor + "%'   ..."
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using
`WHERE g.value like '%" + lookingFor + "'`

Comment: Unfortunately, it will find "abcd efgh" when I type "cd", right?

Answer (score 1):

The % before the lookingFor in sql represents that there might be other data **before** lookingFor.  % after the lookingFor represents that there might be other data **after** lookingFor.

So if you want to find "efg" when you have data like "abcd efgh" you need to do:

```
....WHERE g.value LIKE '%" + lookingFor + "%' ";
```

And yes unfortunately it will find "abcd.." when you type "cd". In order to fix this you can check the value of lookingFor before you actually execute the sql command.

```
if(lookingFor.equals("efg")
{
    ....WHERE g.value LIKE '%" + lookingFor + "%' ";
}
else
{
     //Do whatever you want here if the value is not "efg".
}
```

Good luck

Comment: what about doing like this: before query String strSpace=" "

Comment: WHERE g.value LIKE 'strSpace + lookingFor + "%' "

Comment: The extra space you enter is just being added to lookingFor, so now lookingFor is " efg", that will lead you to the problem you had from the start; i.e. it will not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
Cursor oCursor = myDatabasequery(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[]{column1, column2,column3},  column2+ " LIKE '%" + lookingFor + "%'", null, null, null, null, null);
```

In your code :

```
... WHERE g.value LIKE '%" + lookingFor + "%' "
```

It will search your string whatever before and after that

Comment: How to do it in raw query?

Comment: I have edited please check